# Matching Array numbers with Array names?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My programming lab problem statement:

> Design an algorithm that will prompt for and receive an employee number from an operator at a terminal. your program is to search an array of valid employee numbers to check that the employee number is valid, look up a parallel array to retrieve the corresponding employee name for that number, and display the name to the screen. If the employee number is not valid, an error message is to be displayed.

I'm supposed to enter the employee number, and then it displays the employee name. (also need to give an error message if the number is invalid.)

```
var Emp_num  = new Array(123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901,012);
var Emp_name = new Array("ED","BOB","LOU","JEAN","MAX","SUE","VIC","TOM","CAL","MO");
var i = 1;
Emp_num=prompt("Enter Employee Number: ");
```

Comment: What language is this? PHP?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: you seemed to have stopped right before the user would have entered the employee number.  Are you having trouble getting input from the user?

Comment: design an algorithm that will prompt for and receive an employee number from an operator at a terminal. your program is to search an array of valid employee numbers to check that the employee number is valid, look up a parallel array to retrieve the corresponding employee name for that number, and display the name to the screen. if the employee number is not valid, an error message is to be displayed.

Comment: im completely new to javascript, my first semester actually. and we dont learn the exact things we get assigned, it just seems alot more complex then what we do in class. so im just completely stumped, i guess like a brain fart -.-

Comment: @user3034269 Telling us that you're new to javascript is not going to get you any sympathy from us, but what **will**, get your a warmer reception is telling us exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: not asking for sympathy, wanted to just imply to you i know virtually nothing so im going to sound.. well not "educated" . Sorry about that, but i just dont understand at this point how im supposed to take what i prompted the user for (numbers) and make it display the name that is matched. just extremely confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the return value from `prompt` to `Emp_num` because that's where you're storing the array of your employee numbers. Create a new variable named `Req_num` or something and store it there.

Then you'd just convert the user entry to an integer with `parseInt` and find the `indexOf` that number in `Emp_num`. You could then look up this index in `Emp_name` (if it's greater than -1) to get the employee name, like this:

```
var Emp_num  = new Array(123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901,012);
var Emp_name = new Array("ED","BOB","LOU","JEAN","MAX","SUE","VIC","TOM","CAL","MO");

var Req_num = prompt("Enter Employee Number: ");
var Emp_idx = Emp_num.indexOf(parseInt(Req_num, 10));

if (Emp_idx > -1) {
    alert("Employee name: " + Emp_name[Emp_idx]);
} else {
    alert("Employee number not found.");
}
```

[parseInt docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [indexOf docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujVXv/2/)

Comment: thank you, it makes more sense now that you explained it, but i get an error message. Object doesnt support property or method 'indexOf'

Comment: Then you're not using the code I posted, that error does not occur in the demo. You'll have to debug your code and figure it out. Note that `indexOf` is available on Arrays `[]` or Strings `''`, but not Objects `{}`.